# WPF - TextBox Multiline and Word Selection

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm having an issue when trying to select a word in the textbox by double-clicking it. The textbox is MultiLine and with the properties TextWrapping, Accepts Return and AcceptsTab set to true. If I double-click a small word (less than 70 chars in my test) it works perfectly, but with bigger words other lines or the entire text is selected by clicking this word.

Anyone knows how to fix this?

Code sample (just created a wpf project with the name TestTexbox):

```
<Window x:Class="TestTextbox.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="600" Width="800">
<Grid
    Margin="20">
    <TextBox 
        Text="This is for just a test: 404142434445464748494A4B4C4D4E4F404142434445464748494A4B4C4D4E4F404142434445464748494A4B4C4D4E4F404142434445464748494A4B4C4D4E4F404142434445464748494A4B4C4D4E4F404142434445464748494A4B4C4D4E4F404142434445464748494A4B4C4D4E4F404142434445464748494A4B4C4D4E4F404142434445464748494A4B4C4D4E4F404142434445464748494A4B4C4D4E4F404142434445464748494A4B4C4D4E4F404142434445464748494A4B4C4D4E4F"
        TextWrapping="Wrap"
        TextAlignment="Left"
        FontFamily="Courier New"
        VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
        AcceptsReturn="True"
        AcceptsTab="True"
        AutoWordSelection="True"
        ForceCursor="True"
        Padding="10"/>
</Grid>
```

Also, in this test, depending if you are clicking the start or the end of the string it will select the word or the entire text

Comment: No code, can't reproduce, can't help. Sorry.

Comment: Can you demonstrate using small sample app and post code & XAML?

Comment: Added in the description. Thanks

Comment: I just came across the same behavior. If you found a solution, I'll be happy to hear about it. +1.